# Setting panda series equal to a specific value only if it is between two times

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to set values of the dataframe column `long` equal to 0 if it is between start time and end time.
Could someone make me understand why the first two methods do not work but the last one does?

```
start_time, end_time = '9:30', '9:40'

data.between_time(start_time, end_time)['long'] = 0    (will not work)
data.loc[data.between_time(start_time, end_time).index]['long'] = 0 (will not work)

data['long'].loc[data.between_time(start_time, end_time).index] = 0 (will work)
```

Also, if there is any faster way of doing this than option 3 above, please let me know.

This is more of a pedagogical question. In my ideal world method one will work since it seems to be the most concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is get positions by [`DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html) and set values by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), so is necessary position of column `long` by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
idx = data.index.indexer_between_time(start_time, end_time)

data.iloc[idx, data.columns.get_loc('long')] = 0
```

Similar like your solution is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = data.between_time(start_time, end_time)
data.loc[df.index, 'long'] = 0
```

Performance is similar for 1M rows with sample data, but your solution should be avoid because possible [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters):

```
i = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='H', periods=1000000)

N = len(i)
data = pd.DataFrame({'long':range(N)}, index=i)
start_time, end_time = '9:30', '9:40'

In [287]: %timeit data['long'].loc[data.between_time(start_time, end_time).index] = 0
102 ms ± 4.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [289]: %timeit data.iloc[data.index.indexer_between_time(start_time, end_time), data.columns.get_loc('long')] = 0
96.8 ms ± 856 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [291]: %timeit data.loc[data.between_time(start_time, end_time).index, 'long'] = 0
97.5 ms ± 1.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```